# Is there a way to overlap a content editor webpart on an image in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I want to place a content editor Web Part, on an image. Is it possible to do this in SharePoint Designer 2010?

Comment: Whats your goal with doing this? Placing a web part over top of an image doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add both into the page and use CSS and/or JavaScript to do overlay.